# Generate, from one source, two Debian packages, each installed via its own Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, debian, package

I have one source which contains the sources for 2 packages, each with its own Makefile for both building and installing.

Inside the `debian/rules` file, I do something like

`override_dh_auto_build:
    cd package_1 && make
    cd package_2 && make`

to build the two packages and each have an entry in `debian/controls`.

The problem comes when I want to install them: I can create a `.install` file for each of them, i.e. `debian/package_1.install` and `debian/package_2.install` but I already have their install sorted by running `make install` in each of the package folders.

Is there any way of telling `debuild` that I want to use `Makefile` 1 to install `package_1` and `Makefile` 2 to install `package_2`?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to split them into separate source packages?

Comment: I think you should be able to pull this off just by specifying which files to copy into place for which package in the `debian/package_x.files` files.